# how to get next and previous record id using linq to sql?

Tags: linq-to-sql

```
var product = db.Products.First(p => p.Id == 5);
```

In the product detail show page, show.aspx?Id=5,  I want to get the previous and next product link.

How can I do that?

Should I connect to the database three times to get the current product and previous id and next id for generate links?

Comment: What do you mean under Next and Previous? You just need firs product with the ID lower than 5 and first product with the ID higher than 5, am I right?

Comment: Yes, and I have solved this problem.

Comment: It would be nice if you told us how you solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by returning two entities.